# TWILIO Conference Calls (with different country codes)

Tags: twilio

Just wondering whether a Twilio conference call can involve participants from different countries in the same conference call with Twilio (i.e they may all have different international phone number country codes). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here with a pretty straightforward answer for you.

They absolutely can!

Answer (score 2):

As Phil says - yes they can. Purchase the numbers in the geographic location required then configure that number to the request URL of the [conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) that joins them to the same room.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Joining a conference room</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Conference>YourConferenceRoom</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```